# how to handle create account -button which has href link (anchor tag) using selenium webdriver in java

Tags: java, selenium

**i need to catch the create account -button which has  href link   (anchor tag) using selenium webdriver in java**

```
<p class="create_account">Don't have an account?<a href="http://www.signsigma.com/customer/account/create/" class="create_account">Create an account!</a></p>
```

Comment: What have you tried and what was the result? Please read the help topics on [ask]. You need to research your own issue, find code samples, etc. and write your own code to solve the issue. If you do all that and still can't figure it out, then come back and edit your question and add notes from the research you did, the code you have tried reduced to a [mcve], and what the result was... any error messages, etc. It's also very important to include any relevant HTML and properly format the HTML and code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try below

```
driver.findElement(By.linkText("Create an account!")).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

try locating using the following css selector:

```
p[class='create_account']
```

this should be the easiest way to find it.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `cssSelector` as below :-

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);

wait.until(elementToBeClickable(By.ccssSelector("a.create_account"))).click();
```

or using `linkText` as below :-

```
wait.until(elementToBeClickable(By.linkText("Create an account!"))).click();
```

or using `partialLinkText` as below :-

```
wait.until(elementToBeClickable(By.partialLinkText("Create an account"))).click();
```

or using `xpath` as below :-

```
wait.until(elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//a[contains(.,'Create an account!')]"))).click();
```

Hope it helps...:)